# Searching array of hashes to see if specific elements in a given hash match any string within another array in Ruby

Tags: arrays, ruby, hash

Given the following code:

```
cons = [
  { "FirstName" => "Bill",
    "LastName" => "Wingy",
    "Phone1" => "(800) 552-3209",
    "Phone2" => "828 283-1134" 
  },
  { "FirstName" => "Ted",
    "LastName" => "Dimble",
    "Phone1" => "(823) 813-2834",
    "Phone2" => "8823 232-2342"
  }
]

pait_nums = [ "8282831134", "8282831132344" ]
```

How do you search the `cons` array to return the hash where either `"Phone1".gsub(/\D/, '')` or `"Phone2".gsub(/\D/, '')`matches any string within the `pait_nums` array?

Comment: If you do this frequently, you could build a lookup table that maps (stripped) phone numbers to their respective entries.

Answer (score 2):

```
phones = ["Phone1", "Phone2"]
cons.find { |h| (h.values_at(*phones).map { |s| s.gsub(/\D/,"") } & pait_nums).any? }
  #=> {"FirstName"=>"Bill",
  #    "LastName"=>"Wingy",
  #    "Phone1"=>"(800) 552-3209",
  #    "Phone2"=>"828 283-1134"}
```

The steps:

`find` initially passes the first value of `cons` to the block and sets the block variable `h` to that value:

```
h = { "FirstName" => "Bill",
      "LastName" => "Wingy",
      "Phone1" => "(800) 552-3209",
      "Phone2" => "828 283-1134" }
```

The following block calculations are then performed:

```
a = h.values_at(*phones)
  #=> ["(800) 552-3209", "828 283-1134"]
b = a.map { |s| s.gsub(/\D/,"") }
  #=> ["8005523209", "8282831134"]
c = b & pait_nums
  #=> ["8005523209", "8282831134"] & ["8282831134", "8282831132344"]
  #=> ["8282831134"]
c.any?
  #=> true
```

As `c` is `true`, `find` returns `h`. Were `c` `false`, the second hash would be sent to the block.

Comment: Nice one! You could also use `any?` with a block, e.g. `cons.find { |h| h.values_at(*phones).any? { |s| pait_nums.include?(s.gsub(/\D/, '')) } }`

Answer (score 0):

Let try this:

```
cons.select{ |con| pait_nums.include?(con['Phone1'].gsub(/\D/, '')) || pait_nums.include?(con['Phone2'].gsub(/\D/, '')) }
```

Or make it shorter

```
phone_keys = %w( Phone1 Phone2 )
cons.select{ |con| con.slice(*phone_keys).values.any?{ |val| pait_nums.include?(val.gsub(/\D/, '')) } }
```

Comment: This code throws an exception `NoMethodError: undefined method ‘in?’ for "8005523209":String`.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using rails then you can use `present`in ruby you can use `any?`

```
cons.select{ |con| ([con['Phone1'].gsub(/\D/, ''), con['Phone2'].gsub(/\D/, '')] & pait_nums).present?}
```

In ruby you can use `any?` as

```
 cons.select{ |con| ([con['Phone1'].gsub(/\D/, ''), con['Phone2'].gsub(/\D/, '')] & pait_nums).any?}
```

Comment: There is no such method `Array#present?` in ruby.

Comment: @mudasobwa have you check complete logic what i have done in that?? i have take intersection of both array and if any element found inside it then it means given value is present inside it.

Comment: I don’t need to check any logic: you use methods from external libraries without any notice of that. Your code will just throw `NoMethodError: undefined method ‘present?’ for [...]:Array` exception.

Answer (score 0):

```
cons.select do |c|
  c.select do |k, _|
    k =~ /\APhone\d\z/                     # select Phone* keys
  end.values                               # get values
     .any? do |p|
       pait_nums.include? p.gsub(/\D/, '') # get only matches
     end
end
```

or, for any arbitrary set of keys to check:

```
keys = %w|Phone1 Phone2|
cons.select do |c|
  c.select do |k, _|
    keys.include? k                        # select Phone* keys
  end.values.any? do |p|
    pait_nums.include? p.gsub(/\D/, '')    # get only matches
  end
end
```